# How to find a point from a 2D triangle with two known points and an angle

Tags: trigonometry

i have two points: (5, 10, 0) 'A' and (10, 10, 0) 'B', what is the third point of my triangle if 'B's interior angle is 45degrees? and it's 45degrees horizontal to the axis, not vertical.

[image]

*The third point lies in a plane PARALLEL on the x-z plane.

Comment: Do you mean the third point lies in a plane parallel to $xz$-plane ?

Comment: yes, and i added side lengths too

Comment: @samjoe updated post

Comment: The third point is simply $(10-7\cos(45^{\circ}), 10, 7\sin(45^{\circ}))$

Comment: @samjoe okay is '10' in this equation drawn from point A? or B? and/or both? is this equation a standard equation? how does it work? what is it called?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ lie in $xy$ plane. The x-coordinate of $B$ is $10$. So $x$ coordinate of third point is $10-7\cos(45^{\circ})$. Actually we are taking projection of side with length $7$ on $AB$. Since it lies in a plane parallel to $xz$, the $y$ coordinate is same as the other two points, ie 10. The $z$ coord is the *height* of the triangle, $7\sin(45^{\circ})$

Comment: @samjoe last question, IF 45 was not parallel, but vertical instead, how do i get the new point?

Comment: You mean it would be in the $xy$ plane then? You actually just need to visualise or draw a sketch.

Comment: This question is far too unclear to give an adequate answer.  Parallel (to what?) .... not parallel but "vertical" (vertical with respect to what?)  As has been very well advised:  by other users: "You actually just need to visualise or draw a sketch"....and "The best way to learn these types of problems is to learn basic trigonometry and then use a little 3D.  visualization."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your edited figure, co-ordinates of $C$ would be $x = 10 - 7 \cos{45 ^\circ}$, $y = 10$ and $z =  7 \sin{45^\circ}$.

Comment: thank you, but why is 'cos' in x? and 'sin' in y? what if  45^ was vertical? where can i learn more about these equations? i need to know how to use them

Comment: Sorry, I missed your last point that $C$ lies in x-z plane. Edited the answer. The best way to learn these types of problems is to learn basic trigonometry and then use a little 3D visualization.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the question is ill-posed.

In general the third point $C$ can lie anywhere on a single naped right circular cone with $B$ as apex, (extended) line $AB$ as it's axis and generating angle = 45 degress.

Comment: not if i specify that it's horizontal

Comment: Even then, $C$ can lie anywhere on a straight line which make 45 degree angle with $AB$.

Comment: you are correct, i did not specify the side measurements, this should help now.

Comment: An answer that comments that a question is ill-posed should be a comment, not an answer